# pandas: finding date of specified dayofweek close to other date

Tags: pandas

I am looking to replace `apply` method with something faster for the following problem:

having `day_of_week` and  `closest_date` columns I need to find the `found_dates`, that are of the specified `day_of_week` and are closest prior (backwards) to the `closest_date`, allowing equal to `closest_date` results.

initial `df`:

```
    closest_date  day_of_week
0   2009-06-01    6
1   2014-09-02    0
2   2014-10-11    4
3   2015-01-02    3
4   2015-07-11    4
```

I need to speed-up the following working code:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Week

def find_nearset_day_to_dayofweek(row):
    return row['closest_date'] - Week(weekday=row['day_of_week'])

df['date'] = df.apply(find_nearset_day_to_dayofweek, axis=1)
```

below is just to fix where `found_date` should be equal to `closest_date`, but returns a week before.
    import numpy as np

```
df['closest_date_dayofweek'] = df['closest_date'].dt.dayofweek

df['found_date'] = np.where(df['closest_date_dayofweek']==df['day_of_week'], 
                                              df['closest_date'],
                                              df['found_date'])
df = df.drop(['closest_date_dayofweek'], axis=1)
```

that returns the following `df`

```
    closest_date    day_of_week found_date
0   2009-06-01      6           2009-05-31
1   2014-09-02      0           2014-09-01
2   2014-10-11      4           2014-10-10
3   2015-01-02      3           2015-01-01
4   2015-07-11      4           2015-07-10
5   2015-08-08      4           2015-08-07
```

The problem with the code above is the `apply` method, which is slow. Any ideas of how to speed up?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because possible only `7` values you can use loop with filter only matched rows by another column:

```
for i in range(7):
    m = df['day_of_week'].eq(i)
    df.loc[m, 'date'] = df.loc[m, 'closest_date'] - Week(weekday=i)
```

And then new column is not necessary, use:

```
df['date'] = np.where(df['closest_date'].dt.dayofweek==df['day_of_week'],
                      df['closest_date'], df['date'])
```

Performance for `5000` rows:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Week

def find_nearset_day_to_dayofweek(row):
    return row.closest_date - Week(weekday=row['day_of_week'])

df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [137]: %timeit df['date'] = df.apply(find_nearset_day_to_dayofweek, axis=1)
550 ms ± 77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [138]: %%timeit
     ...: for i in range(7):
     ...:     m = df['day_of_week'].eq(i)
     ...:     df.loc[m, 'date1'] = df.loc[m, 'closest_date'] - Week(weekday=i)
     ...:     
38.1 ms ± 883 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Hello jezreal why it is faster ?

Comment: @OmarAldakar - I think because only 7 loops vs loops  by number of rows, in testing 5000 loops

Comment: Yes but the eq function have to look over the 5000 row of the dataframe to verify the condition. I really dont see why that should be faster

Comment: Is the apply function very inefficient and not just perform the operation over the 5000 lines?